# How to install the latest Filezilla from their server

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I installed filezilla using the Ubuntu Software and the version is 3.7 but according to their website the current stable version is 3.17.

I downloaded the zip file from the [Filezilla project website](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) but not sure how to install it. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the usual PPA is lagging behind (Muench: 3.15) but it is fairly easy to build from source and probably safer than using a precompiled binary. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I can provide some easy copy and paste instructions to build it on your version of Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use the package manager from Ubuntu ... apt-get synaptic. To install it.. it may be a slightly older version (or in this case seems to be a newer version) but it is compiled for Ubuntu. The binaries are compiled for Linux but each flavor of Linux is slightly different.

With the downloaded binaries which it seems  you have downloaded you need to extract the file.

Taken from their site:

```
After extracting the files to any location (location does not matter,
FileZilla can detect its own installation prefix), you can start the
program using the filezilla executable in the bin/ subdirectory. Please 
note that due to differences in distributions, the provided binaries 
might not work on your system.
```